# Serving a docfx site from a fileshare (no webserver)

Tags: docfx

Is there a way to put the output of `docfx build` into a simple folder (e.g. local folder on my computer), load index.html and have the site load correctly? When I try this, the navigation is removed and I believe a base URL would need to be defined somewhere as images reference `c:///images/image.png`

A simple question, but I can't seem to find an answer online nor in docfx doco.